# Error after fabcar chaincode modify-Error: No valid responses from any peers

Tags: node.js, docker, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, chaincode

I am following a tutorial and trying to change the chaincode of **fabcar**   . However i am getting this error.

```
$ cd fabcar/javascript
$ node enrollAdmin.js
    Wallet path: /home/ricky/fabric/fabric-samples/fabcar/javascript/wallet
    Successfully enrolled admin user "admin" and imported it into the wallet
$ node registerUser.js
    Wallet path: /home/ricky/fabric/fabric-samples/fabcar/javascript/wallet
    Successfully registered and enrolled admin user "appUser" and imported it into the wallet
$ node invoke.js
    Wallet path: /home/ricky/fabric/fabric-samples/fabcar/javascript/wallet
    2022-09-24T19:23:05.281Z - error: [Transaction]: Error: No valid responses from any peers. Errors:
        peer=peer0.org2.example.com:9051, status=500, message=error in simulation: transaction returned with failure: ReferenceError: from is not defined
        peer=peer0.org1.example.com:7051, status=500, message=error in simulation: transaction returned with failure: ReferenceError: from is not defined
        at newEndorsementError (/home/ricky/fabric/fabric-samples/fabcar/javascript/node_modules/fabric-network/lib/transaction.js:74:12)
        at getResponsePayload (/home/ricky/fabric/fabric-samples/fabcar/javascript/node_modules/fabric-network/lib/transaction.js:41:23)
        at Transaction.submit (/home/ricky/fabric/fabric-samples/fabcar/javascript/node_modules/fabric-network/lib/transaction.js:255:28)
        at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
        at async main (/home/ricky/fabric/fabric-samples/fabcar/javascript/invoke.js:83:9)
    Failed to submit transaction: Error: No valid responses from any peers. Errors:
        peer=peer0.org2.example.com:9051, status=500, message=error in simulation: transaction returned with failure: ReferenceError: from is not defined
        peer=peer0.org1.example.com:7051, status=500, message=error in simulation: transaction returned with failure: ReferenceError: from is not defined
```

Here are my files:
**fabcar.js**

```
/*
 * Copyright IBM Corp. All Rights Reserved.
 *
 * SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0
 */

'use strict';

const { Contract } = require('fabric-contract-api');

class FabCar extends Contract {

async initLedger(ctx){
    await ctx.stub.putState("test","hello world")
    return "success"
}



async writeJsonData(ctx,key,value){
    let jsonvalue = JSON.parse(value)
    console.log("**********",jsonvalue);
    value=JSON.parse(value)
    await ctx.stub.putState(key,Buffer,from(JSON.stringify(jsonvalue)));
    return Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(jsonvalue));
}

async readData(ctx,key){
    let response = await ctx.stub.getState(key);
    response=response.toString('utf-8')
    return JSON.stringify(response);

}
async queryPatientsByDiagnosis(ctx,diagnosis){
    let queryString = {}
    queryString.selector = {"diagnosis":diagnosis}
    let iterator = await ctx.stub.getQueryresult(JSON.stringify(queryString))
    let result = await this.getIteratorData(iterator)
    return JSON.stringify(result)
}
async getIteratorData(iterator){
    let resultArray =[]
    while(true){
        let res = await iterator.next()
        let resJson = {}
        if(res.value && res.value.value.toString()){
            resJson.key = res.value.key;
            resJson.value=JSON.parse(res.value.value.toString('utf-8'))
            resultArray.push(resJson)
            
}
if(res.done){
    await iterator.close();
    return resultArray
}

    }
}

}

module.exports = FabCar;
```

**enrollAdmin.js**

```
/*
 * Copyright IBM Corp. All Rights Reserved.
 *
 * SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0
 */

'use strict';

const FabricCAServices = require('fabric-ca-client');
const { Wallets } = require('fabric-network');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

async function main() {
    try {
        // load the network configuration
        const ccpPath = path.resolve(__dirname, '..', '..', 'test-network', 'organizations', 'peerOrganizations', 'org1.example.com', 'connection-org1.json');
        const ccp = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(ccpPath, 'utf8'));

        // Create a new CA client for interacting with the CA.
        const caInfo = ccp.certificateAuthorities['ca.org1.example.com'];
        const caTLSCACerts = caInfo.tlsCACerts.pem;
        const ca = new FabricCAServices(caInfo.url, { trustedRoots: caTLSCACerts, verify: false }, caInfo.caName);

        // Create a new file system based wallet for managing identities.
        const walletPath = path.join(process.cwd(), 'wallet');
        const wallet = await Wallets.newFileSystemWallet(walletPath);
        console.log(`Wallet path: ${walletPath}`);

        // Check to see if we've already enrolled the admin user.
        const identity = await wallet.get('admin');
        if (identity) {
            console.log('An identity for the admin user "admin" already exists in the wallet');
            return;
        }

        // Enroll the admin user, and import the new identity into the wallet.
        const enrollment = await ca.enroll({ enrollmentID: 'admin', enrollmentSecret: 'adminpw' });
        const x509Identity = {
            credentials: {
                certificate: enrollment.certificate,
                privateKey: enrollment.key.toBytes(),
            },
            mspId: 'Org1MSP',
            type: 'X.509',
        };
        await wallet.put('admin', x509Identity);
        console.log('Successfully enrolled admin user "admin" and imported it into the wallet');

    } catch (error) {
        console.error(`Failed to enroll admin user "admin": ${error}`);
        process.exit(1);
    }
}

main();
```

**invoke.js**

```
/*
 * Copyright IBM Corp. All Rights Reserved.
 *
 * SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0
 */

'use strict';

const { Gateway, Wallets } = require('fabric-network');
const fs = require('fs');
const { relative } = require('path');
const path = require('path');
const { stringify } = require('querystring');

async function main() {
    try {
        // load the network configuration
        const ccpPath = path.resolve(__dirname, '..', '..', 'test-network', 'organizations', 'peerOrganizations', 'org1.example.com', 'connection-org1.json');
        let ccp = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(ccpPath, 'utf8'));

        // Create a new file system based wallet for managing identities.
        const walletPath = path.join(process.cwd(), 'wallet');
        const wallet = await Wallets.newFileSystemWallet(walletPath);
        console.log(`Wallet path: ${walletPath}`);

        // Check to see if we've already enrolled the user.
        const identity = await wallet.get('appUser');
        if (!identity) {
            console.log('An identity for the user "appUser" does not exist in the wallet');
            console.log('Run the registerUser.js application before retrying');
            return;
        }

        // Create a new gateway for connecting to our peer node.
        const gateway = new Gateway();
        await gateway.connect(ccp, { wallet, identity: 'appUser', discovery: { enabled: true, asLocalhost: true } });

        // Get the network (channel) our contract is deployed to.
        const network = await gateway.getNetwork('mychannel');

        // Get the contract from the network.
        const contract = network.getContract('fabcar');
        
        let key1 = "p1"
        var patient1 = {
        "name":"kumar",
        "diagnosis" : "cancer",
        "hospital": "apollo"
    }
         
         let key2 = "p2"
        var patient2 = {
        "name":"Rajesh",
        "diagnosis" :"diabetes",
        "hospital":"CMS"
    }
    

        let key3 = "p3"
        var patient3= {
        "name":"Rahul",
        "diagnosis" :"diabetes",
        "hospital":"CMS"
    }
    
        let key4 ="p4"
        var patient4 = {
        "name":"Madhu",
        "diagnosis" :"dialysis",
        "hospital":"CMS"
    }

        let key5 = "p5"
        var patient5 = {
        "name":"Ravi",
        "diagnosis" :"angiogram",
        "hospital":"CMS"
    }

        // Submit the specified transaction.
        // createCar transaction - requires 5 argument, ex: ('createCar', 'CAR12', 'Honda', 'Accord', 'Black', 'Tom')
        // changeCarOwner transaction - requires 2 args , ex: ('changeCarOwner', 'CAR12', 'Dave')
        await contract.submitTransaction('writeJsonData',key1,JSON.stringify(patient1));
        await contract.submitTransaction('writeJsonData',key2,JSON.stringify(patient2));
        await contract.submitTransaction('writeJsonData',key3,JSON.stringify(patient3));
        await contract.submitTransaction('writeJsonData',key4,JSON.stringify(patient4));
        await contract.submitTransaction('writeJsonData',key5,JSON.stringify(patient5));
        console.log('Transaction has been submitted');

        // Disconnect from the gateway.
        await gateway.disconnect();
        return;

    } catch (error) {
        console.error(`Failed to submit transaction: ${error}`);
        process.exit(1);
    }
}

main();
```

**query.js**

```
/*
 * Copyright IBM Corp. All Rights Reserved.
 *
 * SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0
 */

'use strict';

const { Gateway, Wallets } = require('fabric-network');
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');


async function main() {
    try {
        // load the network configuration
        const ccpPath = path.resolve(__dirname, '..', '..', 'test-network', 'organizations', 'peerOrganizations', 'org1.example.com', 'connection-org1.json');
        const ccp = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(ccpPath, 'utf8'));

        // Create a new file system based wallet for managing identities.
        const walletPath = path.join(process.cwd(), 'wallet');
        const wallet = await Wallets.newFileSystemWallet(walletPath);
        console.log(`Wallet path: ${walletPath}`);

        // Check to see if we've already enrolled the user.
        const identity = await wallet.get('appUser');
        if (!identity) {
            console.log('An identity for the user "appUser" does not exist in the wallet');
            console.log('Run the registerUser.js application before retrying');
            return;
        }

        // Create a new gateway for connecting to our peer node.
        const gateway = new Gateway();
        await gateway.connect(ccp, { wallet, identity: 'appUser', discovery: { enabled: true, asLocalhost: true } });

        // Get the network (channel) our contract is deployed to.
        const network = await gateway.getNetwork('mychannel');

        // Get the contract from the network.
        const contract = network.getContract('fabcar');

        // Evaluate the specified transaction.
        // queryCar transaction - requires 1 argument, ex: ('queryCar', 'CAR4')
        // queryAllCars transaction - requires no arguments, ex: ('queryAllCars')
       let result = await contract.evaluateTransaction('queryPatientsByDiagnosis','diabetes');
        //console.log(`Transaction has been evaluated, result is: ${result.toString()}`);
        console.log(result)
        result = result.toString('utf-8')
        console.log(result)

        // Disconnect from the gateway.
        await gateway.disconnect();
        
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(`Failed to evaluate transaction: ${error}`);
        process.exit(1);
    }
}

main();
```

This is my **docker ps -a**

```
docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                                                                                                                                                                   COMMAND                  CREATED        STATUS                      PORTS                                                             NAMES
a0907aa1fcae   dev-peer0.org2.example.com-fabcar_1-5186256e9e2b0a552bc2083b79447653343b12fdd8a23edcced41b2c38a4d7f6-e3a5770e7e3aef0a6a8d7ea9e15ff6e514d81a1c08bab41f3ba6e9f6520332b4   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   10 hours ago   Up 10 hours                                                                                   dev-peer0.org2.example.com-fabcar_1-5186256e9e2b0a552bc2083b79447653343b12fdd8a23edcced41b2c38a4d7f6
18b6da067756   dev-peer0.org1.example.com-fabcar_1-5186256e9e2b0a552bc2083b79447653343b12fdd8a23edcced41b2c38a4d7f6-4015ed4ba9ddd130ffb0eed9589fe89bc6f80d2e734a60a9a86bcd8c47341a1e   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   10 hours ago   Up 10 hours                                                                                   dev-peer0.org1.example.com-fabcar_1-5186256e9e2b0a552bc2083b79447653343b12fdd8a23edcced41b2c38a4d7f6
6affdc017949   hyperledger/fabric-tools:latest                                                                                                                                         "/bin/bash"              10 hours ago   Up 10 hours                                                                                   cli
a827cd7c8ac0   hyperledger/fabric-peer:latest                                                                                                                                          "peer node start"        10 hours ago   Up 10 hours                 7051/tcp, 0.0.0.0:9051->9051/tcp, :::9051->9051/tcp               peer0.org2.example.com
672f5857730b   hyperledger/fabric-peer:latest                                                                                                                                          "peer node start"        10 hours ago   Up 10 hours                 0.0.0.0:7051->7051/tcp, :::7051->7051/tcp                         peer0.org1.example.com
692da8ec1a9f   hyperledger/fabric-orderer:latest                                                                                                                                       "orderer"                10 hours ago   Up 10 hours                 0.0.0.0:7050->7050/tcp, :::7050->7050/tcp                         orderer.example.com
f035a0064c8c   couchdb:3.1.1                                                                                                                                                           "tini -- /docker-ent…"   10 hours ago   Up 10 hours                 4369/tcp, 9100/tcp, 0.0.0.0:7984->5984/tcp, :::7984->5984/tcp     couchdb1
b869cb3e0ecd   couchdb:3.1.1                                                                                                                                                           "tini -- /docker-ent…"   10 hours ago   Up 10 hours                 4369/tcp, 9100/tcp, 0.0.0.0:5984->5984/tcp, :::5984->5984/tcp     couchdb0
c55aa294278e   hyperledger/fabric-ca:latest                                                                                                                                            "sh -c 'fabric-ca-se…"   10 hours ago   Up 10 hours                 7054/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8054->8054/tcp, :::8054->8054/tcp               ca_org2
18889ec68ece   hyperledger/fabric-ca:latest                                                                                                                                            "sh -c 'fabric-ca-se…"   10 hours ago   Up 10 hours                 7054/tcp, 0.0.0.0:9054->9054/tcp, :::9054->9054/tcp               ca_orderer
12e416920956   hyperledger/fabric-ca:latest                                                                                                                                            "sh -c 'fabric-ca-se…"   10 hours ago   Up 10 hours                 0.0.0.0:7054->7054/tcp, :::7054->7054/tcp                         ca_org1
8a055dbb0f25   hyperledger/fabric-nodeenv:2.2                                                                                                                                          "docker-entrypoint.s…"   14 hours ago   Exited (0) 14 hours ago                                                                       sharp_jepsen
1ccd7c827ee8   ece149884124                                                                                                                                                            "peer node start"        45 hours ago   Exited (1) 45 hours ago                                                                       peer0.rubbershipperorg3.supplychain.com
75a96497a154   ece149884124                                                                                                                                                            "peer node start"        45 hours ago   Exited (1) 45 hours ago                                                                       peer1.goodscustomorg4.supplychain.com
393023a965dd   ece149884124                                                                                                                                                            "peer node start"        45 hours ago   Exited (1) 45 hours ago                                                                       peer1.rubbershipperorg3.supplychain.com
04d2bdb53161   ece149884124                                                                                                                                                            "peer node start"        45 hours ago   Exited (1) 45 hours ago                                                                       peer1.indonesianfarmorg1.supplychain.com
b850d79cd7f4   ece149884124                                                                                                                                                            "peer node start"        45 hours ago   Exited (1) 45 hours ago                                                                       peer0.goodscustomorg4.supplychain.com
ae4b4f0947f9   ece149884124                                                                                                                                                            "peer node start"        45 hours ago   Exited (1) 45 hours ago                                                                       peer1.usclientorg2.supplychain.com
a4674beea134   78a16ddd2cf4                                                                                                                                                            "orderer"                45 hours ago   Exited (2) 45 hours ago                                                                       orderer2.supplychain.com
03af77cd3fd3   couchdb:3.1.1                                                                                                                                                           "tini -- /docker-ent…"   45 hours ago   Exited (255) 16 hours ago   4369/tcp, 9100/tcp, 0.0.0.0:6984->5984/tcp, :::6984->5984/tcp     couchdb2
eb8b60ce5908   couchdb:3.1.1                                                                                                                                                           "tini -- /docker-ent…"   45 hours ago   Exited (255) 16 hours ago   4369/tcp, 9100/tcp, 0.0.0.0:11984->5984/tcp, :::11984->5984/tcp   couchdb7
35c5c6a6e198   78a16ddd2cf4                                                                                                                                                            "orderer"                45 hours ago   Exited (2) 45 hours ago                                                                       orderer3.supplychain.com
b02c0006e93c   78a16ddd2cf4                                                                                                                                                            "orderer"                45 hours ago   Created                                                                                       orderer.supplychain.com
860178e6cd6b   couchdb:3.1.1                                                                                                                                                           "tini -- /docker-ent…"   45 hours ago   Exited (255) 16 hours ago   4369/tcp, 9100/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8984->5984/tcp, :::8984->5984/tcp     couchdb4
4b4515185dde   couchdb:3.1.1                                                                                                                                                           "tini -- /docker-ent…"   45 hours ago   Created                                                                                       couchdb3
e104998fc7a9   couchdb:3.1.1                                                                                                                                                           "tini -- /docker-ent…"   45 hours ago   Exited (255) 16 hours ago   4369/tcp, 9100/tcp, 0.0.0.0:10984->5984/tcp, :::10984->5984/tcp   couchdb6
ee2b80732cc4   couchdb:3.1.1                                                                                                                                                           "tini -- /docker-ent…"   45 hours ago   Exited (255) 16 hours ago   4369/tcp, 9100/tcp, 0.0.0.0:12984->5984/tcp, :::12984->5984/tcp   couchdb8
04955859f5a6   couchdb:3.1.1                                                                                                                                                           "tini -- /docker-ent…"   45 hours ago   Exited (255) 16 hours ago   4369/tcp, 9100/tcp, 0.0.0.0:9984->5984/tcp, :::9984->5984/tcp     couchdb5
025548def0c4   gliderlabs/logspout                                                                                                                                                     "/bin/logspout"          2 weeks ago    Exited (255) 16 hours ago   127.0.0.1:8000->80/tcp                                            logspout
91bc51f80b88   hyperledger/explorer-db:latest                                                                                                                                          "docker-entrypoint.s…"   3 weeks ago    Exited (255) 3 weeks ago    5432/tcp                                                          explorerdb.mynetwork.com
```

**docker logs container_name**

```
docker logs dev-peer0.org2.example.com-fabcar_1-5186256e9e2b0a552bc2083b79447653343b12fdd8a23edcced41b2c38a4d7f6
+ CHAINCODE_DIR=/usr/local/src
+ cd /usr/local/src
+ npm start -- --peer.address peer0.org2.example.com:9052

> fabcar@1.0.0 start /usr/local/src
> fabric-chaincode-node start "--peer.address" "peer0.org2.example.com:9052"

2022-09-24T19:21:01.940Z info [c-api:contracts-spi/bootstrap.js]                  No metadata file supplied in contract, introspection will generate all the data  
2022-09-24T19:21:02.352Z info [c-api:lib/chaincode.js]                            Registering with peer peer0.org2.example.com:9052 as chaincode "fabcar_1:5186256e9e2b0a552bc2083b79447653343b12fdd8a23edcced41b2c38a4d7f6"  
2022-09-24T19:21:02.502Z info [c-api:lib/handler.js]                              Successfully registered with peer node. State transferred to "established"  
2022-09-24T19:21:02.504Z info [c-api:lib/handler.js]                              Successfully established communication with peer node. State transferred to "ready"  
2022-09-24T19:21:02.564Z info [c-api:lib/handler.js]                              [mychannel-1f33601d] Calling chaincode Init() succeeded. Sending COMPLETED message back to peer  
********** { name: 'kumar', diagnosis: 'cancer', hospital: 'apollo' }
2022-09-24T19:23:05.239Z error [c-api:contracts-spi/chaincodefromcontract.js]     [mychannel-84269974] ReferenceError: from is not defined  
2022-09-24T19:23:05.243Z error [c-api:lib/handler.js]                             [mychannel-84269974] Calling chaincode Invoke() returned error response [ReferenceError: from is not defined
    at FabCar.writeJsonData (/usr/local/src/lib/fabcar.js:24:33)
    at ChaincodeFromContract.invokeFunctionality (/usr/local/src/node_modules/fabric-shim/lib/contract-spi/chaincodefromcontract.js:378:58)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)]. Sending ERROR message back to peer
```

i tried several solution including[solution link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65204924/error-no-valid-responses-from-any-peers-failed-to-execute-transaction-could-no) but its still giving me same result.I dont know where else to change to fix the following issue. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

There is an error in your chaincode in 4th line of the function writeJsonData().

> await ctx.stub.putState(key,Buffer,from(JSON.stringify(jsonvalue)));

It should be `Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(jsonvalue))`

Comment: thanks @basilky. However i faced new error while invoking now `Error: Failed to connect before the deadline on Endorser- name: peer0.org1.example.com, url:grpcs://localhost:7051, connected:false, connectAttempted:true error: [ServiceEndpoint]: waitForReady - Failed to connect to remote gRPC server peer0.org1.example.com url:grpcs://localhost:7051 timeout:3000`